# Verifying LP solutions using primal-dual hybrids

Tags: linear-programming, primal-dual

We wish to solve an LP in the standard form

> Choose vector $x$ to maximize $c^T x$ subject to $Ax \le b$.

Let $x^*$ be a feasible point.  By LP duality, $x^*$ solves the LP iff we can write the objective vector $c$ as a positive linear combination of the constraints that are tight at $x^*$.  Formally:

> **Theorem (LP Duality):** Let $R^*$ be the set of row vectors $r_i$ in $A$ for which $r_i x^* = b_i$.  Then $x^*$ is an optimal solution to the LP if and only if $c^T \in \text{posspan}(R^*)$.

I am looking for a relaxed version of this theorem statement, where we verify $x^*$ by handling some constraints in $R^*$ in a dual manner as above, and the rest in a primal manner.  My ideal theorem statement looks something like the following:

> **Theorem I am looking for:** Let $R^* = R^*_1 \cup R^*_2$ be a partition of $R^*$, and suppose that $x^*$ maximizes the LP over the subset of feasible points in which all constraints in $R^*_1$ are tight.  Then $x^*$ is an optimal solution to the LP if and only if *[some conditions hold that depend only on $R^*_2$]*.

Is a theorem statement of this form known, or is there anything morally related (such as [conditions] that depend on $R^*_1$ only in a relaxed or simplified way)?

Comment: This scenario arises with Lagrangian-relaxation (multiplicative-weights update) algorithms.  I believe the classical name for it is "surrogate duality".  Roughly, order the constraints in any order, then take the first $k$ constraints for some $k$ and relax these by removing them from the LP and replacing them by a single constraint that is a linear combination of them, with coefficients given by some vector $\mu\in\mathbb R^k$.  The theorem is that, for the best choice of $\mu$, this relaxed problem has the same value as the original problem (the relaxation gap is zero)...

Comment: Maybe something like the "Duality Theorem" at the bottom of page 446 of https://leeds-faculty.colorado.edu/glover/fred%20pubs/60%20-%20surrogate%20-%20theory%20-%20OR%2075.pdf ?  (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.23.3.434)

Comment: Thanks Neal - this will take me a minute to parse, but at a glance it looks very helpful.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you'd like to discuss more.